# Splitting a tuple into multiple tuples in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I like to generate multiple tuples from a single tuple. What I mean is: 
I have file with following data in it.

```
>> cat data
ID | ColumnName1:Value1 | ColumnName2:Value2
```

so I load it by the following command

```
grunt >> A = load '$data' using PigStorage('|');    
grunt >> dump A;    
(ID,ColumnName1:Value1,ColumnName2:Value2)
```

Now I want to split this tuple into two tuples.

```
(ID, ColumnName1, Value1)
(ID, ColumnName2, Value2)
```

Can I use UDF along with foreach and generate. Some thing like the following?

```
grunt >> foreach A generate SOMEUDF(A)
```

EDIT:

input tuple :  (id1,column1,column2)
output : two tuples (id1,column1)  and (id2,column2) so it is List or should I return a Bag?

```
public class SPLITTUPPLE extends EvalFunc <List<Tuple>>
{
    public List<Tuple> exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            // not sure how whether I can create tuples on my own. Looks like I should use TupleFactory.
            // return list of tuples.
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write a UDF or use a PIG script with built-in functions.

For example:

```
-- data should be chararray, PigStorage('|') return bytearray which will not work for this example
inpt = load '/pig_fun/input/single_tuple_to_multiple.txt' as (line:chararray);

-- split by | and create a row so we can dereference it later
splt = foreach inpt generate FLATTEN(STRSPLIT($0, '\\|')) ;

-- first column is id, rest is converted into a bag and flatten it to make rows
id_vals = foreach splt generate $0 as id, FLATTEN(TOBAG(*)) as value;
-- there will be records with (id, id), but id should not have ':'
id_vals = foreach id_vals generate id, INDEXOF(value, ':') as p, STRSPLIT(value, ':', 2) as vals;
final = foreach (filter id_vals by p != -1) generate id, FLATTEN(vals) as (col, val);
dump final;
```

**Test INPUT:**

```
1|c1:11:33|c2:12
234|c1:21|c2:22
33|c1:31|c2:32
345|c1:41|c2:42
```

**OUTPUT**

```
(1,c1,11:33)
(1,c2,12)
(234,c1,21)
(234,c2,22)
(33,c1,31)
(33,c2,32)
(345,c1,41)
(345,c2,42)
```

I hope it helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I do the same thing with writing an UDF. I update the question.

Comment: Yes you can. See next answer.

Comment: Its great help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hey,
I tried running your use case and then got stuck with the following error:

grunt> id_vals = foreach id_vals generate id, INDEXOF(value, ':') as p, STRSPLIT(value, ':', 2) as vals;

2016-03-18 16:41:24,677 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1045:
<line 8, column 65> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.STRSPLIT as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Kindly update the relation accordingly to avoid the exception.

Comment: Over the years the interfaces might have changed, had that in the past. Which version of pig are you using?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the UDF version. I prefer to return a BAG:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;
import org.apache.pig.data.BagFactory;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataBag;
import org.apache.pig.data.DataType;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException;
import org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.schema.Schema;

/**
 * Converts input chararray "ID|ColumnName1:Value1|ColumnName2:Value2|.." into a bag 
 * {(ID, ColumnName1, Value1), (ID, ColumnName2, Value2), ...}
 *  
 *  Default rows separator is '|' and key value separator is ':'. 
 *  In this implementation white spaces around separator characters are not removed.
 *  ID can be made of any character (including sequence of white spaces). 
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class TupleToBagColumnValuePairs extends EvalFunc<DataBag> {

    private static final TupleFactory tupleFactory = TupleFactory.getInstance();
    private static final BagFactory bagFactory = BagFactory.getInstance();

    //Row separator character. Default is '|'.
    private String rowsSeparator;
    //Column value separator character. Default i
    private String columnValueSeparator;

    public TupleToBagColumnValuePairs() {
        this.rowsSeparator = "\\|";
        this.columnValueSeparator = ":";
    }

    public TupleToBagColumnValuePairs(String rowsSeparator, String keyValueSeparator) {
        this.rowsSeparator = rowsSeparator;
        this.columnValueSeparator = keyValueSeparator;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a tuple with 3 fields (id:chararray, column:chararray, value:chararray)
     * @param outputBag Output tuples (id, column, value) are added to this bag
     * @param id
     * @param column
     * @param value
     * @throws ExecException
     */
    protected void addTuple(DataBag outputBag, String id, String column, String value) throws ExecException {
        Tuple outputTuple = tupleFactory.newTuple();
        outputTuple.append(id);
        outputTuple.append(column);
        outputTuple.append( value);
        outputBag.add(outputTuple);
    }

    /**
     * Takes column{separator}value from splitInputLine, splits id into column value and adds them to the outputBag as (id, column, value)
     * @param outputBag Output tuples (id, column, value) should be added to this bag
     * @param id 
     * @param splitInputLine format column{separator}value, which start from index 1
     * @throws ExecException
     */
    protected void parseColumnValues(DataBag outputBag, String id,
            String[] splitInputLine) throws ExecException {
        for (int i = 1; i < splitInputLine.length; i++) {
            if (splitInputLine[i] != null) {
                int columnValueSplitIndex = splitInputLine[i].indexOf(this.columnValueSeparator);
                if (columnValueSplitIndex != -1) {
                    String column = splitInputLine[i].substring(0, columnValueSplitIndex);
                    String value = null;
                    if (columnValueSplitIndex + 1 < splitInputLine[i].length()) {
                        value = splitInputLine[i].substring(columnValueSplitIndex + 1);
                    }
                    this.addTuple(outputBag, id, column, value);
                } else {
                    String column = splitInputLine[i];
                    this.addTuple(outputBag, id, column, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * input - contains only one field of type chararray, which will be split by '|'
     * All inputs that are: null or of length 0 are ignored.
     */
    @Override
    public DataBag exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() != 1 || input.isNull(0)) {
            return null;
        }

        String inputLine = (String)input.get(0);
        String[] splitInputLine = inputLine.split(this.rowsSeparator, -1);

        if (splitInputLine.length > 1 && splitInputLine[0].length() > 0) {
            String id = splitInputLine[0];
            DataBag outputBag = bagFactory.newDefaultBag();            
            if (splitInputLine.length == 1) { // there is just an id in the line
                this.addTuple(outputBag, id, null, null);
            } else {
                this.parseColumnValues(outputBag, id, splitInputLine);
            }


           return outputBag; 
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Schema outputSchema(Schema input) {
        try {
            if (input.size() != 1) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Expected input to have only one field");
            }

            Schema.FieldSchema inputFieldSchema = input.getField(0);
            if (inputFieldSchema.type != DataType.CHARARRAY) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Expected a CHARARRAY as input");
            }

            Schema tupleSchema = new Schema();
            tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("id", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("column", DataType.CHARARRAY));
            tupleSchema.add(new Schema.FieldSchema("value", DataType.CHARARRAY));

            return new Schema(new Schema.FieldSchema(getSchemaName(this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase(), input), tupleSchema, DataType.BAG));
        } catch (FrontendException exx) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exx);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is how it is used in PIG:

```
register 'path to the jar';
define IdColumnValue myPackage.TupleToBagColumnValuePairs();

inpt = load '/pig_fun/input/single_tuple_to_multiple.txt' as (line:chararray);
result = foreach inpt generate FLATTEN(IdColumnValue($0)) as (id1, c2, v2);
dump result;
```

A good inspiration for writing UDFs with bags see [DataFu source code by LinkedIn](https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/tree/master/src/java/datafu/pig/bags)

Answer (score 0):

You could use TransposeTupleToBag (UDF from DataFu lib) on the output of STRSPLIT to get the bag, and then FLATTEN the bag to create separate row per original column.