# PIG - Converting elements of bags into fields

Tags: apache-pig

I have a Pig query with the following output (one row)

> (6,{(6,76,35,1565),(6,76,76,920),(6,35,76,906),(6,177,35,822),(6,268,35,720),(6,35,177,701),(6,35,268,694),(6,35,35,656),(6,85,85,611),(6,35,90,559)})

I would like to transform each element of my bag into a field, so

> (6,(6,76,35,1565),(6,76,76,920),(6,35,76,906),(6,177,35,822),(6,268,35,720),(6,35,177,701),(6,35,268,694),(6,35,35,656),(6,85,85,611),(6,35,90,559))

where I can name every field with a different name :  x1, x2, x3,....,
I tried flattening but that made one row for each element of the bag:

> 6,(6,76,35,1565)
>
> 6,(6,76,76,920)
>
> 6, (6,35,76,906)

And I want all the elements to remain in one single row.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try the following links it may be helpfull

1.[How to convert fields to rows in Pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427889/how-to-convert-fields-to-rows-in-pig)

2.[write array from pig](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/177)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use [BagToTuple](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/BagToTuple.html).Assuming you have a relation A with 2 fields.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE A.$0,FLATTEN(BagToTuple(A.$1));
```