# In Apache Pig how can I serialise columns into rows?

Tags: rows, apache-pig, dynamic-columns

In [Apache Pig](http://pig.apache.org) I want to serialise columns held in a variable into rows. More specifically:

The data, loaded into the variable, look (via `DUMP`) like

```
(val1a, val2a,.... )
(val1b, val2b,val3b,.... )
(val1c, val2c,.... )
.
.
.
```

and I want to transform this into

```
(val1a)
(val2a)
.
.
.
(val1b)
(val2b)
(val3b)
.
.
.
(val1c)
(val2c)
.
.
.
```

So, each column has to be "serialised" into rows and then these rows are added subsequently. Please note: I do not necessarily know how many columns are in each row.

How can I do this in [Pig Latin](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html)? It would be easy in, e.g., Python, but I don't know how to do it in Pig. I tried different `foreach` ... `generate` constructs, but could not make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to unfold tuples and create multiple tuples, each containing one field:

```
$ cat data.txt
val1a,val2a,val3a,val4a,val5a,val6a,val7a
val1b,val2b,val3b
val1c,val2c
```

```
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage(',');
B = foreach A generate FLATTEN(TOBAG(*));
dump B;

(val1a)
(val2a)
(val3a)
(val4a)
(val5a)
(val6a)
(val7a)
(val1b)
(val2b)
(val3b)
(val1c)
(val2c)
```

Note:
You might also check these similar posts:
[Splitting a tuple into multiple tuples in Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287362/splitting-a-tuple-into-multiple-tuples-in-pig)

[Pivot table with Apache Pig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11213567/pivot-table-with-apache-pig)

Comment: Great and correct answer. I've tested it and it works as described. The links to the similar posts certainly enrich it further. Thanks.